# How do we solve an AXSpeechAssetDownloader error on iOS?

Tags: ios, avspeechsynthesizer

We have an iOS app that uses AVSpeechSynthesizer to speak. It works on the iPad and other devices - but we notice it is not working on our iPhone 6 Plus.

When examining the console output we see this error:

> |AXSpeechAssetDownloader|error| ASAssetQuery error fetching results
>   Error Domain=ASError Code=21 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (ASError error 21 - Unable to copy asset information)"
>   UserInfo=0x174a7e100 {NSDescription=Unable to copy asset information}

The device on which the app is running does have a network connection.

Any ideas how to even begin solving this?

Comment: We're having the exact same issue, though for us it's happening on devices running iOS 9.

Comment: After moving to iOS8 seeing the same problem:

|AXSpeechAssetDownloader|error| ASAssetQuery error fetching results Error Domain=ASError Code=21 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (ASError error 21 - Unable to copy asset information)" UserInfo=0x174473e00 {NSDescription=Unable to copy asset information}
2015-07-09 10:56:33.371 xxxxxxxx[6275:1073856] Building MacinTalk voice for asset: (null)

Comment: This is on iPadAir with iOS8.4

Comment: Seeing exactly the same problem on iOS 8.4 on an iPod Touch. Tried @softwarenerd's suggestion below, but didn't help.

Comment: Seeing this issue today, where the *exact* same project was running fine yesterday. Exactly the same, in fact, the same project itself as i simply closed my laptop down then cmd-R'd today to continue testing. No errors yesterday, failure today. Oddly the actual speak works fine, as the voice i call in code is my preferred voice, so i assume it is defaulting to that.

Comment: There must be something basically wrong with how we are setting this up, given so few references to solutions to this issue. I will make a note to dig through Apple samples looking for an implementation of this functionality to see if i can discern the real issue. My text is being spoken properly, but the ugly error messages are keeping me from using this feature in a submission.

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue. I couldn't find any help, so, I had to debug it by trying various things.

What I found is that if you access Settings -> General -> Speech, and enable "Speak Selection" and muck about with the English voice, it will just start working for you.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: It works for me, do you know why is happening that? I have an iPod touch 5G and an iPhone 5S and works without that config. But with the six plus start to crash

Comment: there is no Speech in Settings\General iOS10.1.1 it is in Accessibility and it still shows that error

Answer (score 3):

This means that the resources required to speak the required languages have not been downloaded, and the app failed to do that automatically. as @softwarenerd mentions, you can go to Settings -> General -> Speech, and then go to Voices and download whatever voices you need.

But then, this is not really a good solution if you are developing the app for the app store. There must be a way to handle the download automatically and on demand.

Comment: This is not an answer, at least for me. I have explicitly matched my code to my device's preferred voice, and no change, still seeing:

"|AXSpeechAssetDownloader|error| ASAssetQuery error fetching results (for com.apple.MobileAsset.MacinTalkVoiceAssets) Error Domain=ASError Code=21 "Unable to copy asset information" UserInfo={NSDescription=Unable to copy asset information}"

Answer (score 2):

I see the exact same problem on iOS9. Here is my work-around, which is not perfect but at least avoids the crash.

```
let voices = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices()
for voice in voices {
    if lang == voice.language {
        utterance.voice = voice
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume that the lang  variable implementation `let lang = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")`
`

Answer (score 2):

You may see this error also if you are passing string into AVSpeechUtterance constructor in language A, but asking to speech it using language B.

Example:

```
let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Hello")
utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "pl-PL")
```

In this case "Hello" is not a Polish language (pl-PL).
App shows such Error and may (in some cases) speeches text.

Comment: This was exactly the case for me.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I was able to resolve this by setting the utterance.voice **after** the utterance string.

```
speechUtterL1 = AVSpeechUtterance(string: ("أتمنى لك نهارا سعيد")) 
speechUtterL1.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "ar-SA")
```

The reverse, where I set the voice only once results in an error:

> [TTS] Error running custom voice query Error Domain=ASError Code=15
>   "Unable to copy asset information from https://mesu.apple.com/assets/
>   for asset type com.apple.MobileAsset.VoiceServices.GryphonVoice"
>   UserInfo={NSDescription=Unable to copy asset information from
>   https://mesu.apple.com/assets/ for asset type
>   com.apple.MobileAsset.VoiceServices.GryphonVoice}